# Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind. Entity new_test has duplicate navigation property names

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using CRM2016

I created a test entity to replicate the issue

I did not do any customization on it. I created a new record with default fields and form. Then I tried to access the webapi for it

```
http://localhost/CRMDataBase/api/data/v8.0/new_test(bgcs0249-0a06-e611-941a-003002djlnc)
```

It worked fine and brought the record. Then I deleted the records and created a business process flow for it, with just one stage and one step

I activated it and added a new test record and tried to access the webapi url and it threw the below error

> {   "error":{
>       "code":"","message":"Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind. Entity new_test has duplicate navigation property
>   names. All property names (Navigation and Structural property) must be
>   unique in an Entity ","innererror":{
>         "message":"Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind. Entity new_test has duplicate navigation property
>   names. All property names (Navigation and Structural property) must be
>   unique in an Entity
>   ","type":"Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException","stacktrace":"   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateSelectExpandNode(EntityInstanceContext
>   entityInstanceContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataEntityTypeSerializer.WriteEntry(Object
>   graph, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataFeedSerializer.WriteFeed(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, IEdmTypeReference feedType, ODataWriter writer,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataFeedSerializer.WriteObject(Object
>   graph, Type type, ODataMessageWriter messageWriter,
>   ODataSerializerContext writeContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type
>   type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content,
>   TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()","internalexception":{
>           "message":"Property 'stageid' is of an unrecognized EdmPropertyKind.","type":"Microsoft.OData.Core.ODataException","stacktrace":"
>   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectPathSegmentTokenBinder.ConvertNonTypeTokenToSegment(PathSegmentToken
>   tokenIn, IEdmModel model, IEdmStructuredType edmType, ODataUriResolver
>   resolver)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Visitors.SelectPropertyVisitor.ProcessTokenAsPath(NonSystemToken
>   tokenIn)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Visitors.SelectPropertyVisitor.Visit(NonSystemToken
>   tokenIn)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectBinder.Bind(SelectToken
>   tokenIn)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken
>   tokenIn)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.Parsers.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Bind(IEdmStructuredType
>   elementType, IEdmNavigationSource navigationSource, ExpandToken
>   expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration
>   configuration)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.OData.Core.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpand()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataEntityTypeSerializer.CreateSelectExpandNode(EntityInstanceContext
>   entityInstanceContext)"
>         }
>       }   } }

If I delete all the records-> deactivate business process -> add new data and then check the webapi, it is working fine. But when I activate the business process and add new data I am getting the above error
P.S: I have not done any coding/customization to business process flow and the entity. But I am still getting this error

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: Even i am facing this issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Looks more like bug in API generation, tried contacting MS Support?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Web API endpoint. [Community forums](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/198911) also reference the same issue...

The Web API endpoint still has some limitations and it doesn't fully mimic the  OrganizationService behavior so, which will be for the next version (9.x.x)  so if you are stuck maybe try applying an update (and then use v8.1 in the url) as, or raise a MS Support case.

If you are still stuck, just try the same using OData / OrganizationService maybe.